# Why is this variable being changed?

Tags: python, equality, while-loop

```
tokens_raw = {"foo": "bar"}
tokens_raw_old = { }
while not tokens_raw == tokens_raw_old:
    tokens_raw_old = tokens_raw
    # while loop that modifies tokens_raw goes here;
    # tokens_raw_old is never referenced
    print tokens_raw_old == tokens_raw
```

This outputs True after the first time for some reason. `tokens_raw_old` has the same data as `tokens_raw`, even after `tokens_raw` alone was modified. Did I make a dumb mistake somewhere, or does the problem lie within the second while loop (which, again, never once references `tokens_raw_old`)? If there are no obvious mistakes, I'll post more code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tokens_raw_old = tokens_raw` means: make a new reference called `token_raw_old` to the **same** object to which name `tokens_raw` refers at this time.  It's the **same** object, **not** a copy of the object!  So, changes to this one and only object made through one of the references obviously also affect the very same object when examined through the other reference.

If you want a copy, ask for a copy!  For example, since `tokens_raw` is a dict with immutable values (and keys, but that's frequent in dicts):

```
tokens_raw_old = tokens_raw.copy()
```

will be sufficient.  Identically (just a style issue), so will

```
tokens_raw_old = dict(tokens_raw)
```

(make a copy by "calling the type as a copy constructor", a concept that appeals to C++ programmers -- of which I'm one, so I really like this form;-).

If you need to cover for a general case (`tokens_raw` being of many possible different types, or values within it being perhaps modified):

```
import copy

tokens_raw_old = copy.deepcopy(tokens_raw)
```

This can be quite slow, but, "when you need it, you need it" -- it makes a **deep** copy of the object, that is, it doesn't just copy the container but also all contained objects (recursively, if a container contains other containers -- say that three times fast...;-).

Not every object can be copied (deeply or shallowly) -- for example, an open file object cannot be copied (you need other approaches if you ever have such weird, advanced needs).  But, for a dict with strings as keys and values, the simple approaches I mentioned at the start of this answer will suffice, and be quite speedy too;-).

Comment: I actually made a mistake in the code I pasted; tokens_raw is a list, not a dict, so .copy() isn't a valid method. However, the response still makes sense, and I've found that using `tokens_raw_old = tokens_raw[:]` has the same effect as what you suggested. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @Fraxtil, sure, but I personally loathe the ever-popular `somelist[:]` idiom -- `list(somelist)` is just **so** much more readable as a way to shallow-copy a list (or, make a list version of any input sequence, for that matter).  Ah well, matter of style, I guess!-)